# DataFrame does not work well with my for loop

Tags: python, pandas

My for loop doesn't work well as soon as I update my DataFrame (I am not a programmer. I am using python 2.7.15). my code is not efficient, but still should to work, so please do not change my loop, tell me how to change the DataFrame only.

The downloaded DataFrame (from AlphaVantage) looks like this:

```
      Open     High     ...     8. split coefficient    datetime
0  31.1100  31.3500     ...                   1.0000  2018-07-23
1  31.2900  31.3100     ...                   1.0000  2018-07-20
2  28.4800  29.1200     ...                   1.0000  2018-07-26
3  28.8200  29.3350     ...                   1.0000  2018-07-27
4  30.4500  30.9400     ...                   1.0000  2018-07-24
```

As soon as I update to my DataFrame to looks like this:

```
               Open     High      Low    Close AdjClose    Volume
datetime                                                         
2018-07-23  31.1100  31.3500  30.6000  30.8200  30.8200   6023310
2018-07-20  31.2900  31.3100  30.8450  31.1100  31.1100   5022452
2018-07-26  28.4800  29.1200  27.5500  28.9800  28.9800  10582061
2018-07-27  28.8200  29.3350  27.7050  28.1300  28.1300   8101362
2018-07-24  30.4500  30.9400  29.9650  30.1400  30.1400   5706941
```

As soon as run the program with my loop, I got this error:

```
TypeError: cannot insert DatetimeIndex with incompatible label
```

The relevant part of the code is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib as plt
.
. 
.
  df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
    df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(inplace=False)
    # extract the default columns
    df = df[columns] 
    return df

df = df_from_response(data)     
df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=False)   # Current day on top data frame        

A=pd.DataFrame(df)
print (A.head(5)) #3             
Len=len(A)
print (Len)

# Upward and Downward movement calculation 
for Rw in range(Len-1):            
    def adj(A):

        adj_N=float(A.iloc[Rw,4])
        adj_O=float(A.iloc[Rw+1,4])
        #print (adj_N,adj_O)

        if adj_N>adj_O:
            x1=adj_N-adj_O
            x2=0   

        else:
            x1=0
            x2=adj_O-adj_N

        A.at[Rw+1,'UpMv']=x1    
        A.at[Rw+1,'DownMv']=x1 
    adj(A)
print (A.head())
```

When I change  line df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True) to "False", the "for loop" works well, but the DataFrame is change, and the index "datetime" disappear (it sense, because "inplace=False") and looks like this:

```
      Open     High      Low    Close AdjClose    Volume  UpMv  DownMv
0  31.1100  31.3500  30.6000  30.8200  30.8200   6023310   NaN     NaN
1  31.2900  31.3100  30.8450  31.1100  31.1100   5022452  0.00    0.00
2  28.4800  29.1200  27.5500  28.9800  28.9800  10582061  2.13    2.13
3  28.8200  29.3350  27.7050  28.1300  28.1300   8101362  0.85    0.85
4  30.4500  30.9400  29.9650  30.1400  30.1400   5706941  0.00    0.00
```

As you can see, the index "datetime" disappear, but i have my wanted two new columns.
So, how can i see index "datetime" with my new columns?
Again, please keep my "for loop as is".

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `A.iloc[Rw,4]` where `Rw` is an integer, but your index is set to be a datetime, from your `.set_index()` call.

You shouldn't be doing a for loop here - one of the joys of `pandas` is its ability to work much more quickly through vectorised operations. In particular, you appear to be wanting to use `.shift()` to compare against the previous day's values, which you can do like so:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = StringIO('''datetime               Open     High      Low    Close AdjClose    Volume
2018-07-23  31.1100  31.3500  30.6000  30.8200  30.8200   6023310
2018-07-20  31.2900  31.3100  30.8450  31.1100  31.1100   5022452
2018-07-26  28.4800  29.1200  27.5500  28.9800  28.9800  10582061
2018-07-27  28.8200  29.3350  27.7050  28.1300  28.1300   8101362
2018-07-24  30.4500  30.9400  29.9650  30.1400  30.1400   5706941''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df['Mv'] = df['AdjClose'] - df['AdjClose'].shift(1)

print(df)
```

Which gives us the following dataframe:

```
             Open    High     Low  Close  AdjClose    Volume    Mv
datetime                                                          
2018-07-20  31.29  31.310  30.845  31.11     31.11   5022452   NaN
2018-07-23  31.11  31.350  30.600  30.82     30.82   6023310 -0.29
2018-07-24  30.45  30.940  29.965  30.14     30.14   5706941 -0.68
2018-07-26  28.48  29.120  27.550  28.98     28.98  10582061 -1.16
2018-07-27  28.82  29.335  27.705  28.13     28.13   8101362 -0.85
```

Comment: thanks for your response! It's a little problematic for me to use the formula you wrote, because i have a lot more loops, that i will have to insert later on. The loops include complex formulas that i do not know how to write (as i mentioned, i am not programmer). my loop are work well. i believe the problem is interfacing between the DataFrame to the loop. as i mentioned earlier, if i change df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True) to "False", the loop works well, but index dissapear. the key for the solution is to find the interface between DataFrame to the loop....Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you use A.at with integers. However you set your index to datetime.
Use A.iat instead or iterate over the index using:

```
for Rw in range(Len-1):   
    df.iat[Rw, 'column']

for index in A.index:
    df.at[index, 'column']
```

And do the same for A.loc[].